# Backbone.js - defining json array within model

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

here is my model code:

```
exports.definition = {

config: {

    columns: {

         "id": "TEXT",

        "nickname": "TEXT",

        "date_of_birth": "TEXT",

        "pictures":[],

        "email":"TEXT",

        "gender": "TEXT",

        "description": "TEXT"

    },

    adapter: {

        type: "sql",

        db_name: "dbname",

        collection_name: "user"

    }

},
```

For pictures I would like to define a JSON array which will then be populated dynamically.

I have tried pictures: []  but it throws up an error. What is the best way to do this, thanks

Error:

[ERROR] :      line = 15;

[ERROR] :      message = "'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'name.split(/\s+/)')";

[ERROR] :      name = TypeError;

[ERROR] :      sourceId = 309198272;

Comment: What error did you see?

Comment: updated my question - type error

Comment: Think i have solved it, not sure  - changed [] to "[]"

Comment: found the problem, the above works - but sql lite does not support arrays. So I have had to store the object as a json string,

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that SQLlite does not have support for storing objects into the database.

If you find yourself in this situation. Simply store the JSON string into the database, then get the database object and parse it into a JSON object.

Once you have done that, you should be able to access the elements via a for loop.